# Question about tutorial "Publishing Odometry Information over ROS"

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom

it says:

Add the dependancy to your package's manifest.xml

```
<depend package="tf"/>
<depend package="nav_msgs"/>
```

i dont have manifest.xml, i have package.xml and if i add it there it returns errors. where do i put it and how do i run the code from tutorial??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292368/question-about-tutorial-%22publishing-odometry-information-over-ros%22/) by [topkek](https://answers.ros.org/users/34642/topkek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2018-05-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

manifest.xml is used in the legacy rosbuild build system while package.xml is used in the catkin build system

In package.xml, you need to add the following lines:

```
<build_depend>nav_msgs</build_depend>
<build_depend>tf</build_depend>

<run_depend>nav_msgs</run_depend>
<run_depend>tf</run_depend>
```

In addition, you can find the complete code for this tutorial at this link:

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation_tutorials/tree/indigo-devel/odometry_publisher_tutorial

---

Originally posted by [mntan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35508/mntan/) with karma: 51 on 2018-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1